# Capture Sound from Mirophone and speakers

Tags: python, python-sounddevice, amazon-transcribe

We are using amazon transcribe to make speach to text but we need to capture sound from both microphone and speakers. Do you think that this can be done with sounddevice or should we use something else?

[amazon-transcribe-streaming-sdk](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-transcribe-streaming-sdk/blob/develop/examples/simple_mic.py)

- Mic Function

```
async def mic_stream():
    # This function wraps the raw input stream from the microphone forwarding
    # the blocks to an asyncio.Queue.
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    input_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    def callback(indata, outdata, frame_count, time_info, status):
        '''
        if status:
            print(status)
        '''
        #indata[:] = outdata
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(input_queue.put_nowait, (bytes(indata), status))

    # Be sure to use the correct parameters for the audio stream that matches
    # the audio formats described for the source language you'll be using:
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/streaming.html
    stream = sounddevice.RawStream(
        #device=3,
        channels=1,
        samplerate=16000,
        callback=callback,
        blocksize=1024 * 2,
        dtype="int16",
    )
    # Initiate the audio stream and asynchronously yield the audio chunks
    # as they become available.
    with stream:
        while True:
            indata, status = await input_queue.get()
            yield indata, status
```

Comment: hello guys

We have tested the script with varius devices. With Corsair HS45 Surround USB Sound Adapter i was able to capture sound from both microphone and speakers, but with HP X1000 Wireless Gaming Headsetwe are unable to get any data from speakers. 

Can anyone help?